# How can go to another activity when click on any item in Expandablelistview?

Tags: android

Where can I add the code of click on item in order to go to another activity?

```
side_screen.java
package com.example.asus.myapplication;

import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.widget.ExploreByTouchHelper;
import android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuView;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Action;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Thing;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class side_screen extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    HashMap<String, List<String>> Computer_category;
    List<String> Computer_list;
    ExpandableListView Exp_list;
    ComputerAdapter adapter;

    int photo_num;
    ImageView imageView;
    private GoogleApiClient client;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_side_screen);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("meun");
        toolbar.setSubtitle("courses");

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        Exp_list = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.exp_list);
        Computer_category = DataProvider.getInfo();
        Computer_list = new ArrayList<String>(Computer_category.keySet());
        adapter = new ComputerAdapter(this, Computer_category, Computer_list);
        Exp_list.setAdapter(adapter);

        Exp_list.setOnItemClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            }
        });
        Intent searchintent = getIntent();
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(searchintent.getAction())) {
            String query = searchintent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);

            Toast.makeText(side_screen.this, query, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_show);
        final ImageButton but_next = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.next);
        final ImageButton but_back = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.back);
        but_next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (photo_num < 4) {
                    photo_num++;
                    imageView.setImageResource(getResources().getIdentifier("bri_".concat(String.valueOf(photo_num)), "drawable", getPackageName()));
                    but_back.setEnabled(true);
                } else {
                    but_next.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }
        });
        but_back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (photo_num > 1) {
                    photo_num--;
                    imageView.setImageResource(getResources().getIdentifier("bri_".concat(String.valueOf(photo_num)), "drawable", getPackageName()));
                    but_next.setEnabled(true);
                } else {
                    but_back.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.side_screen, menu);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(SEARCH_SERVICE);
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.item1) {
            finish();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    public Action getIndexApiAction() {
        Thing object = new Thing.Builder()
                .setName("menu courses") // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated URL is correct.
                .setUrl(Uri.parse("http://[ENTER-YOUR-URL-HERE]"))
                .build();
        return new Action.Builder(Action.TYPE_VIEW)
                .setObject(object)
                .setActionStatus(Action.STATUS_TYPE_COMPLETED)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        client.connect();
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, getIndexApiAction());
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, getIndexApiAction());
        client.disconnect();
    }

    public void but_wel(View view) {
        TextView texwel= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcome);
        Intent intent=new Intent(this,com_under.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}

ComputerAdapter.java

package com.example.asus.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by ASUS on 20/09/16.
 */
public class ComputerAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    private Context cxt;
    private HashMap<String,List<String>>Computer_Category;
    private List<String>Computer_List;
    public ComputerAdapter(Context cxt,HashMap<String,List<String>>Computer_category,List<String>Computer_list){
        this.cxt=cxt;
        this.Computer_Category=Computer_category;
        this.Computer_List=Computer_list;
    }


    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return Computer_List.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int arg0) {
        return Computer_Category.get(Computer_List.get(arg0)).size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int arg0) {
        return Computer_List.get(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int parent, int child) {
        return Computer_Category.get(Computer_List.get(parent)).get(child);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int arg0) {
        return arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int parent, int child) {
        return child;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int parent, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parentview) {
        String group_title= (String) getGroup(parent);
        if (convertView==null){
            LayoutInflater inflator= (LayoutInflater) cxt.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView=inflator.inflate(R.layout.parent_layout,parentview,false);
        }
        TextView parent_txetview= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.parent_txt);
        parent_txetview.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        parent_txetview.setText(group_title);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int parent, int child, boolean LastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parentview) {
        String child_title= (String) getChild(parent,child);
        if (convertView==null){
            LayoutInflater inflater= (LayoutInflater) cxt.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_layout,parentview,false);
        }
        TextView child_textview= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chlid_txt);
        child_textview.setText(child_title);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Is there any code I must add it here?

```
DataProvider.java

package com.example.asus.myapplication;

import android.widget.ExpandableListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by ASUS on 20/09/16.
 */
public class DataProvider {
    public static HashMap<String,List<String>>getInfo()
    {
        HashMap<String,List<String>>ComputerDetails=new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
                List<String>Computer_Engineering=new ArrayList<>();
        Computer_Engineering.add("UNDERGRUATE");
        Computer_Engineering.add("GRUATE");
        List<String>Software_Engineering=new ArrayList<>();
        Software_Engineering.add("UNDERGRUATE");
        Software_Engineering.add("GRUATE");
        List<String>Information_Engineering=new ArrayList<>();
        Information_Engineering.add("UNDERGRUATE");
        Information_Engineering.add("GRUATE");
        ComputerDetails.put("Computer Engineering",Computer_Engineering);
        ComputerDetails.put("Software Engineering",Software_Engineering);
        ComputerDetails.put("Information Engineering",Information_Engineering);
        return ComputerDetails;



    }
}
```

note: the `expandablelistview` in the end of activity:

side_screen.Xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.example.asus.myapplication.side_screen"
    android:background="#d6d7d7">
    <include layout="@layout/toolbar"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"/>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:background="@drawable/cover"
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"

        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Welcome To Labib Academey "
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
            android:id="@+id/welcome"
            android:onClick="but_wel"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#025e1e"/>


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Now,choose your cours from "
            android:textSize="23dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/welcome2"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#025e1e"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=" computer sciences below."
            android:textSize="23dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/welcome3"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#025e1e"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#0a5951"

        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="The best websites in computer science"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
android:paddingBottom="15dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:textSize="19dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="375dp"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="#0a5951"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="390dp" >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Computer courses"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:gravity="center"/>
    </LinearLayout>



    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#f7f3f3"
        android:layout_marginTop="260dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="270dp"
            android:layout_height="140dp"
            android:id="@+id/image_show"
            android:src="@drawable/bri_4"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout3"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:id="@+id/next"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_next1"
            android:background="@color/color0"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout3"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:id="@+id/back"
            android:background="@color/color0"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_back1"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/next"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/scroll"
            android:background="#f9f7f7"
            android:layout_marginTop="450dp">


            <ExpandableListView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/exp_list"
                android:divider="#A4C739"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:paddingRight="15dp"
                android:dividerHeight="1dp"
                android:indicatorRight="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredChildIndicatorRight"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"/>
        </LinearLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```

parent_screen.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/parent_txt"
    android:textColor="#1a912c"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Please help my as soon as possible.

Comment: Your question is extremely bad.. If I got your question right then you just need to start an activity at `Exp_list.setOnItemClickListener`. For a guy who has written so much code, shouldn't be hard to know this small thing... If I got your question wrong then you gotta write in detail on what you want..

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a listener on your ExpandableListView and in it open the activity:

```
  listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    // Launch the activity
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, ActivityToOpen.class);
    context.startActivity(intent);
});
```

Comment: for example i would like to go to anther activity when click on first item under second address...how can write that, please

Comment: I'm not sure to understand exactly what you want to do. If you mean to open the activity only when clicking the first item of the list, you can check if position is equal to 0 inside the click listener. If so the open the activity.

Comment: If  my answer solved your issue, please mark it as correct answer! Cheers!